# Verify login on state change in AngularJS doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, states

I want to verify if the user can access a state before he gets there, if he doesn't have permissions will be redirected to another page.
The problem is that I'm doing a SPA and it verifies the permissions, but it takes a while until the server send the response and the user is redirected, so what happen is that a screen appears for 1 or 2 seconds and then is redirected successfully. Is there anyway to avoid this?

This is the code for the state change:

```
webApp.run(function ($rootScope, $state, StateService) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, fromState, toParams) {

        StateService.hasAccessTo(toState.name, function(data){
            if (data.data != ""){
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go(data.data);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

and the service:

```
webApp.service('StateService', function($http, $rootScope){
    this.hasAccessTo = function(state, callback){
        $http.get("state/" + state).then(callback);
    }
});
```

I have also tried with a promise in the `$stateChangeStart`, but it didn't work.

I read about interceptors, but they work if the user is in another page and access mine, if he is already on the page and type a link manually it doesn't intercepts.

Any modifications or suggestions of new ideas or improvements are welcome!

**EDIT**

Now I have this:

```
var hasAccessVerification = ['$q', 'StateService', function ($q, $state, StateService) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    StateService.hasAccessTo(this.name, function (data) {
        if (data.data !== '') {
            $state.go(data.data);
            deferred.reject();
        } else {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}];

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
$stateProvider
    .state('welcome',{
        url:"/",
        views: {
            'form-view': {
                templateUrl: '/partials/form.html',
                controller: 'Controller as ctrl'
            },
            '@': {
                templateUrl: '/partials/welcome.html'
            }
        },
        data: {
            requireLogin: false
        },
        resolve: {
            hasAccess: hasAccessVerification
        }
    })
```

And it validates, but it doesn't load the template. It doesn't show de views. What might I be doing wrong?

**EDIT 2**

I forgot to add $state here:

```
var hasAccessVerification = ['$q', '$state', 'StateService', function ($q, $state, StateService){...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [`resolve`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) in your state configuration instead of using `$stateChangeStart` event.

According to the docs:

> If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and
>   converted to a value before the controller is instantiated and the
>   `$stateChangeSuccess` event is fired.

Example:

```
var hasAccessFooFunction = ['$q', 'StateService', function ($q, StateService) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    StateService.hasAccessTo(this.name, function (data) {
        if (data.data !== '') {
            $state.go(data.data);
            deferred.reject();
        } else {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}];

$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        resolve: {
            hasAccessFoo: hasAccessFooFunction
        }
    })

    .state('user', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/user',
        resolve: {
            hasAccessFoo: hasAccessFooFunction
        },
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state('user.create', {
        url: '/create',
        templateUrl: 'views/user/create.html'
    })
    .state('user.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'views/user/list.html'
    })
    .state('user.edit', {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: 'views/user/edit.html'
    })
    .state('visitors', {
        url: '/gram-panchayat',
        resolve: {
            hasAccessFoo: hasAccessFooFunction
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/visitor/list.html'
    });
```

And according to the docs https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies **`resolve` are inherited**:

> **New in version 0.2.0**
>
> Child states will inherit resolved dependencies from parent state(s),
>   which they can overwrite. You can then inject resolved dependencies
>   into the controllers and resolve functions of child states.

But, please note:

> The `resolve` keyword **MUST** be on the state not the views (in case you
>   use multiple views).

Comment: I've already tried with that but it didn't work well. Can you show me an example? I'm using inheritance between states, as far as I know the resolve is not inherited, how can I solve that?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: I might have missunderstood something. Thank you! I will try that when I have a moment!

Comment: Where do I have to inject toState? In this case toState is the state where I put the resolve, how can I get the name?

Comment: Oops!! Well it's simple, use `this.name` instead of `toState.name`

Comment: I 've just edited the question because something is not working well

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to have `interceptor` on `responseError` which checks the response status and acts accordingly:

```
webApp.config(['$httpProvider' ($httpProvider) {
    var interceptor = ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
                return {
                    request: function (config) {
                        // can also do something here
                        // for example, add token header
                        return config;
                    },

                    'responseError': function (rejection) {
                        if (rejection.status == 401 && rejection.config.url !== '/url/to/login') {
                             // If we're not on the login page
                             $rootScope.$broadcast('auth:loginRequired');
                          }
                        }
                        return $q.reject(rejection);
                    }

                }
            }];
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
}]);
```

And handle redirection in `run` block

```
webApp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
     $rootScope.$on('auth:loginRequired', function () {
                $state.go('loginState');
            });
}]);
```

The good thing is that `$state` service does not need to deal with permission logic:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('someState', {
            url: '/some-state',
            templateUrl: '/some-state.html',
            resolve: {
                dataFromBackend: ['dataService', function (postingService) {
                    // if the request fails, the user gets redirected
                    return dataService.getData();
                }],
            },
            controller: function ($scope, dataFromBackend) {

            }
        })
```

**Notice**

With this approach, you do not need `StateService`, all you need to do is to return proper response statuses from backend. For example, if the user is guest, return `401` status.

Comment: At the momento I'm returning the state where it has to be redirected if he can't access. As far as I know the interceptors are useful when the user type an URL on the address bar, right? Because if he is already on the page the interceptor doesn't work (when I tried it I had this problem)

Comment: No, `interceptor` intercepts every ajax http request made by angular's `$http` service. And what I am suggesting is to target these requests, not states in your application

Comment: That's a good point. Anyway, is easier for me to manage that with the state change. Thank you for the explanation!